# copy/move same name multiple files in different folder

Tags: linux, command, mv

I have multiple files in different folders with the same name and extension. For example: There are 460 folders and each folder has one file with the name of snps.vcf. I want to copy/move these files to one folder and later on, I will do some analysis that I need to do.

I have tried:

```
find -type f -name "*.vcf" -exec cp {} /home/AWAN/try';'
```

but this code overwrites the files and only one file remains there in the end.

I have tried rename but I don't know how to select multiple files by find command then rename. Even with the mmv I couldn't find the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an external script and pass it to `-exec`.
Your script may use [mktemp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) to generate a random file name. Example:

```
mktemp /your/directory/try-XXX
```

The XXX part will be replaced by mktemp with a different value for each call.